# Show cached image after relaunch of app with AlamofireImage

Tags: ios, swift, image, caching, alamofireimage

I have a problem with Alamofire Image lib.
I try to download an image and then kill the app and switch off wifi. So I expect to see the image (cached in store the first time) when I launch my app without connexion but my image doesn't appears.

Here my code in a simple UIViewController with one UIImage and one UIButton which allows to refresh the view just for some tests :

```
import UIKit
import AlamofireImage

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var firstImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!

var imageCache: ImageRequestCache = AutoPurgingImageCache()
let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/image/jpeg")!)

@IBAction func refreshView(_ sender: Any) {
    self.requestFirstImage()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.requestFirstImage()
}

func requestFirstImage() {

    let downloader = self.diskImageDownloader()
    downloader.download(self.urlRequest) { response in
        if let image = response.result.value {
            self.firstImage.image = image
            // Add image to cache
            self.imageCache.add(image, for: self.urlRequest, withIdentifier: "wolf")
            self.descriptionLabel.text = "Image added to cache"
        }
    }

    // If image is stored in cache show it
    if let image = self.imageCache.image(for: self.urlRequest, withIdentifier: "wolf") {
        self.firstImage.image = image
        self.descriptionLabel.text = "Image showed from cache"
    } else {
        self.descriptionLabel.text = "Impossible to show image from cache"
        // call image from disk here
        ------> Here how read image which is located in alamofireimage_disk_cache subfolder of the app ?
    }

}

func diskImageDownloader(diskSpaceMB: Int = 300) -> ImageDownloader {

    let diskCapacity = diskSpaceMB * 1024 * 1024
    let diskCache = URLCache(memoryCapacity: diskCapacity, diskCapacity: diskCapacity, diskPath: "alamofireimage_disk_cache")
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.urlCache = diskCache
    let downloader = ImageDownloader(configuration: configuration)
    UIImageView.af_sharedImageDownloader = downloader

    return downloader
}   
}
```

In advance thank you for your help.

Kind Regards,

Comment: did you see any error/message  in debug console?

Comment: I tried your code it's working perfect . Try App Transport security settings in info.plist once

Comment: Hi and first thank you for your help but it doesn't works. When I kill my app, switch off connection of device and relaunch it the image is not showed from cache. Nothing appears. Any other idea ?

I tried App Transport security but nothing change.

In advance thank you,

Kind Regards,

Comment: For information my image is downloaded and available in "fsCachedData" subdirectory of "image_disk_cache" directory. How can I fetch it from alamofire image in code ? In advance thank you.

Answer (score 0):

SDWebImage did the trick. When I download my image the first time and then kill my app. If after that I relaunch it without Internet the Image will be showed.

Here one example :

```
import SDWebImage

@IBOutlet weak var myImage: UIImageView!            
let imageURL = URL(string:"Replace by url of image")

self.myImage.sd_setImage(with: imageURL!, placeholderImage:UIImage(named: "PlaceHolderImage")!)
```

For your information "PlaceHolderImage" is the name of my place holder image in assets. So replace by your. This image will appear before/during the download of image.

Don't forget to install SDWebImage lib. Three ways to use this lib in your project :

- using CocoaPods
- using Carthage
- by cloning the project into your repository

Thank you and good luck.